# pass arraylist from VBscript to BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have a txt file which contains some names. I need those names to be
read by a VBscript, store them in an array list and pass it to a BAT file.
How can I pass the array list to the BAT file?

Here is the vbscript:

```
Dim objFile, strLine(), WshShell, intsize
intSize = 0 
Redim Preserve strLine(intsize)
Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile= objFSO.OpenTextFile("read.txt", 1)
Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine(intsize) = objFile.readline
  ReDim Preserve strLine(intSize + 1)
Loop
set WshShell=Wscript.Createobject("Wscript.shell")
    Wshshell.run "test.bat " & strLine(intSize)
objFile.Close
```

bat file

```
@echo off
echo %1
```

Comment: Why do you have to use the vbscript at all? You can create an array from a file directly in batch.

Answer (score 0):

`Join` function returns a string created by joining a number of substrings contained in an array.

*Syntax*: `Join( list[, delimiter])`

*Arguments*:

- `list`: Required. One-dimensional array containing substrings to be joined.
- `delimiter`: Optional. String character used to separate the substrings in the returned string. If omitted, the space character (`" "`) is used. If delimiter is a zero-length string, all items in the list are concatenated with no delimiters.

Surrounding the list with `"` parentheses causes it will appear as the only parameter (`%1`) in the called batch. Your `run` method line then could be as follows:

```
Wshshell.run "test.bat """ & Join( strLine, ";") & """"
```

And a side note: missing array index incrementing in your loop; here is an *almost bulletproof* code snippet:

```
intSize = -1
ReDim strLine( 0)
strLine( 0) = ""
Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream
  intSize = intSize + 1
  ReDim Preserve strLine( intSize)
  strLine( intsize) = objFile.readline
Loop
```